How do I draw 90 degree angle arrows and background
I am trying to recreate this graph

How do I draw axis-aligned arrows and how can I draw a background?
\documentclass[9pt, landscape, twocolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}[English]

\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% \usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
% \usepackage{latexsym}
% \usepackage{array}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=black, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

% \usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most,listings]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colframe=white}

\usepackage{multirow}

% Margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
left=0.75in,
right=0.75in,
top=1in,
bottom=1in
}

% Header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Juan Da Silva}
\lhead{Machine Learning}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\lfoot{TUM}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying

% Titles
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% \newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{\normalsize\bfseries #1}\mbox{}\\}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

% Definitions, theorems, and propositions
% \newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
% \newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}
% \newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
% \newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}
% \newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
% \newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}

% Equation counters
% \counterwithin*{equation}{section}
% \counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt}

% Plots
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

    {\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, yshift=0.0cm, ->, >=Stealth, auto, semithick, node distance=2cm]
        
        \tikzstyle{empty}=[fill=none, draw=none, minimum size=0.75cm]
        \tikzstyle{signstate}=[draw=yellow!75, circle, minimum size=0.25cm, fill=yellow!15, inner sep=0.5pt]
        \tikzstyle{xstate}=[draw=LimeGreen!75, rounded corners, minimum size=0.75cm, fill=LimeGreen!15]
        \tikzstyle{ystate}=[draw=red!75, rounded corners, minimum size=0.75cm, fill=red!15]
        \tikzstyle{state}=[fill=none, draw=none, minimum size=0.5cm]
        \tikzstyle{coord}=[fill=none, draw=none]

        \node[empty] (empty1) {};
        \node[signstate, right=1.5 of empty1] (times1) {$\times$};
        \node[state, above=0.5 of times1] (waa) {$W_{aa}$};
        \node[state, right=0.75 of waa](by){$b_y$};
        \node[state, right=0.75 of by](g2){$g_2$};
        \node[signstate, below=0.15 of g2] (odot1) {$\odot$};
        \node[signstate, below=0.15 of odot1] (plus1) {$+$};
        \node[signstate, right=0.75 of g2] (times2) {$\times$};
        \node[state, right=0.75 of times2] (wya) {$W_{ya}$};
        \node[state, below=0.5 of wya] (g1) {$g_1$};
        \node[signstate, left=0.35 of g1] (odot2) {$\odot$};
        \node[empty, right=1.5 of g1] (empty2) {};
        \node[signstate, below=0.5 of plus1] (times3) {$\times$};
        \node[state, left=0.75 of times3] (wax) {$W_{ax}$};
        \node[state, below=0.5 of g1] (ba) {$b_{a}$};
        \node[ystate, above=0.75 of g2](y){$y^{\langle t\rangle}$};
        \node[xstate, below=0.75 of times3](x){$x^{\langle t\rangle}$};
        \node[coord, left=1 of ba](coordinate1){};
        \node[signstate, left=0.15 of odot2](plus2){$+$};

        \path (empty1) edge node[near start, above] {$a^{\langle t-1 \rangle}$} (times1);
        \path (waa) edge (times1);
        \path (plus1) edge (odot1);
        \path (odot1) edge (g2);
        \path (wya) edge (times2);
        \path (g2) edge (y);
        \path (odot2) edge (g1);
        \path (g1) edge node[near end, above] {$a^{\langle t \rangle}$} (empty2);
        \path (wax) edge (times3);
        \path (x) edge (times3);
        \path (times3) edge (plus2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \par}
\end{document}


Note that you shouldn't use \tikzstyle any more. Use \tikzset instead. Are you looking for |- and -|? Not sure what you mean by 'axis aligned'. Are you trying to change a tcolorbox background or add a background within the tikzpicture? If the latter, why include tcolorbox in your example here?

@cfr Exactly, I mean -| and |-. But I don't know why it is not drawing it. I am trying to add a background within the tikzpicture as in the photo

You can't use it with edge? Is that the issue?

I'd recommend the |- and -| syntax, with the extended versions from tikzext for the lines. For the background, use backgrounds and fit to fit the background to the nodes you want it to contain.
For example (with minor positioning adjustments),
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,ext.paths.ortho,backgrounds,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    baseline={(current bounding box.center)}, 
    yshift=0.0cm, 
    ->, 
    >=Stealth, 
    auto, 
    semithick, 
    node distance=2cm,
    empty/.style={fill=none, draw=none, minimum size=0.75cm},
    signstate/.style={draw=yellow!75, circle, minimum size=0.25cm, fill=yellow!15, inner sep=0.5pt},
    xstate/.style={draw=LimeGreen!75, rounded corners, minimum size=0.75cm, fill=LimeGreen!15},
    ystate/.style={draw=red!75, rounded corners, minimum size=0.75cm, fill=red!15},
    state/.style={fill=none, draw=none, minimum size=0.5cm},
    coord/.style={fill=none, draw=none},
  ]
  
  \node[empty] (empty1) {};
  \node[signstate, right=1.5 of empty1] (times1) {$\times$};
  \node[state, above=0.5 of times1] (waa) {$W_{aa}$};
  \node[state, right=0.75 of waa](by){$b_y$};
  \node[state, above right=0 and 0.75 of by](g2){$g_2$};
  \node[signstate, below=0.35 of g2] (odot1) {$\odot$};
  \node[signstate] (plus1) at (odot1 |- times1) {$+$};
  \node[signstate] [](times2) at ([xshift=7.5mm]g2.east |- waa) {$\times$};
  \node[state, right=0.75 of times2] (wya) {$W_{ya}$};
  \node[state] (g1) at (wya |- times1) {$g_1$};
  \node[signstate, left=0.35 of g1] (odot2) {$\odot$};
  \node[empty, right=1.5 of g1] (empty2) {};
  \node[signstate, below=0.5 of plus1] (times3) {$\times$};
  \node[state, left=0.75 of times3] (wax) {$W_{ax}$};
  \node[state, below=0.5 of g1] (ba) {$b_{a}$};
  \node[ystate, above=0.75 of g2](y){$y^{\langle t\rangle}$};
  \node[xstate, below=0.75 of times3](x){$x^{\langle t\rangle}$};
  \node[coord, left=1 of ba](coordinate1){};
  \node[signstate, below left=0.15 of odot2](plus2){$+$};
  
  \path (empty1) edge node[near start, above] {$a^{\langle t-1 \rangle}$} (times1);
  \path (waa) edge (times1);
  \path (plus1) edge (odot1);
  \path (odot1) edge (g2);
  \path (wya) edge (times2);
  \path (g2) edge (y);
  \path (odot2) edge (g1);
  \path (g1) edge coordinate [pos=.2] (c1)  node[near end, above] {$a^{\langle t \rangle}$} (empty2);
  \path (wax) edge (times3);
  \path (x) edge (times3);
  \path [draw] (times3) -| (plus2);
  \foreach \i/\j in {ba/plus2,plus2/odot2,times1/plus2,by/plus1}
  \path [draw] (\i) |- (\j);
  \foreach \i/\j in {times2/plus1}
  \path [draw] (\i) -|- (\j);
  \foreach \i/\j in {times2/c1}
  \path [draw,-] (\i) |-| (\j);
  \scoped[on background layer]{\node [fit=(waa) (wya) (ba) (wax) (g2) (c1),fill=blue!15,draw=blue!30,rounded corners] {};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


